I want to get video data using a get() request and then extract the embede code
I'll start with an example
To get embedded code on the Vimeo platform I use the following Python code:
def get_vimeo_embed(video_url):
    response = requests.get(f"https://vimeo.com/api/oembed.json?url={video_url}")
    response = response.json()
    response_embed = response["html"]
    return response_embed

Vimeo provides a link where you can get data about the video, and then extract the iframe itself using the "html" key
I didn’t find anything similar in the YouTube documentation, tell me where I can find such a link or another tool
I want to get video data using a get() request as described above
Couldn't find any information

You can use googleapi.
For your need: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos
